# How to find the list of stack on which you depend?

Tags: ros, stack, rospackage, dependencies, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a personnal stack "ard", and I would like to find the list of other stack I depend on. I have all my packages that declares other dependencies in their manifest.xml, and I would like to create the list of stacks that contains a package that is in all those manifests.

They underground aim is to create a "ligth" embedded ros distribution with only the required stuff for the robot, and keep a full ROS electric distribution on my development host.

An easy way would be to copy all directories find by "rosstack depends ard"
but this suppose that my stack.xml file is completed correctly, but it is currently out of sync with the bunch of manifest.xml. So is it a way to automate this completion ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10876/how-to-find-the-list-of-stack-on-which-you-depend-?/) by [Willy Lambert](https://answers.ros.org/users/168/willy-lambert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 352 on 2011-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`roscreate-stack` actually does that for you. After changing the dependencies of any package in your stack, just call `roscreate-stack` on it. It will not overwrite your existing stack.xml but just update the stack dependencies if necessary.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Willy Lambert](https://answers.ros.org/users/168/willy-lambert/) on 2011-08-11**:
I am now able to select the required package. How could I generate the setup.sh automatically ?

**Comment by [Willy Lambert](https://answers.ros.org/users/168/willy-lambert/) on 2011-08-11**:
great and there are comments in the generated file with only the target packages !!! so awesome